# the use of "piled"

Tags: grammar, participial-adjectives

> *"Between the chair and Polly, and filling most of the middle of the
> room, was a big table **piled** with all sorts of things."*

According to my view, in that sentence 'piled' is a verbal adjective attached the the noun table. But that's not the table which is piled but the 'all sorts of things'...In fact, I don't understand the construction of the end of this sentence.

what I have understood :

*"Between the chair and Polly, and filling most of the middle of the
room, was a big table, **on which were piled** all sorts of things."*

Comment: The verb _to pile_ can mean both _to heap things up_ and _to load a surface with things_.

Comment: Yes, "piled" is an adjective here with a meaning similar to "stacked". "Piled with all sorts of things is thus an adjective phrase modifying "table".

Comment: @BillJ, I know you've got a handy set of tests for whether something is an adjective or a participle (or a noun adjunct etc).  Can you use these to demonstrate to a sceptic that "piled" is an adjective.

Comment: @JamesK I take it be an adjective because it has a stative meaning rather than a dynamic one. For "piled" to be a verb it would have to be a passive clause, but it would be difficult to reformulate it as an active clause with a direct object: we can't really say "All sorts of things piled a big table".

Comment: In fact, even the OP's sentence is a tad unusual: we might more naturally say "... a big table piled _up_ with all sorts of things".

Comment: @BillJ  Any particular reason you think "piled *up*" is more natural than simply "piled"?  [Ngrams suggests the opposite.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piled+with%2Cpiled+up+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpiled%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiled%20up%20with%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @JamesK I'm no BillJ, but my litmus test for this situation is whether there's an agent connected with the verb/adjective in question. In. *"These walls are painted every five years"*, there is an agent: the painters who do the painting every year. In, "*These walls are painted beautifully*", there is no agent because as the verb "are" is in the present, and there's nobody who regularly paints the walls, so it's an adjective. This test applies to this sentence, because there's no agent piling books on the table at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "piled" has at least two different meanings:

> "I piled *the table* with books."

> "I piled *books* on the table."

These sentences both mean the same thing even though the direct object in one is the indirect object in the other.

In your example sentence, the word "piled" is an adjective, but the same meaning applies even to adjectives:

> "The books are piled on the table."

> "The table is piled with books."

These describe the exact same situation, only changing the focus to the table or to the books.

Answer (score 1):

"Piled" is an adjective here with a meaning similar to "stacked". "Piled with all sorts of things" is thus an adjective phrase modifying "table".

I take it be an adjective because it has a stative meaning rather than a dynamic one. For "piled" to be a verb it would have to be a passive clause, but it would be difficult to reformulate it as an active clause with a direct object: we can't really say *"All sorts of things piled a big table".